# How do I refer to the control from one of its events?

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there an easier way of getting the 'panelDown' object, in order to have the same code in all controls?

```
    private void panelDown_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        **panelDown**.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rather than using `as` in the way that Nico has suggested, I'd cast:

```
private void panelDown_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var panel = (Panel) sender;
    panel.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
}
```

When you're converting *unconditionally*, using a cast is preferrable as if you've got the wrong type, the exception thrown (`ClassCastException`) is much clearer than getting a `NullReferenceException` when you use the result of an `as` with the wrong input.

(You don't *have* to use two statements here, of course - I just find it clearer.)

Use `as` when it's *valid* for the input to be of a different type, and you'll *conditionally* take action if it's the right type.

If you're wiring up the event handler manually, you can capture the relevant variable instead using a lambda expression, of course:

```
foo.MouseHover += (sender, args) => foo.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
```

Or:

```
foo.MouseHover += delegate { foo.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle };
```

Comment: Thought it would be something simple and easy :) Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

```
private void panelDown_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    (sender as Panel).BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

cast `sender` to your Control (may be Panel).

```
((Panel) sender).BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
```